# Questions on the formula for 2x2 inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

Hi I was working on inverting 2by2 matrix in general form by using a,b,c,d.
I know the formula (which is below) but I have questions in the process of getting the formula.
[image: inverting 2by2 matrix]

1) To get rid of the second column, it seems like the order of subtraction matter. How can you tell which one should be subtracted by the other? Because to get zero, it's possible either way.

Clarified in the comments:

> I meant that to get (0,1) vector for column 2, I used linear transformation (same as I did for column 1). And the first element needs to be zero. In order to get zero, I have two ways. $b(b2)-(ad-cd)(b1)$ or $(ad-cd)(b1)-b(b2)$ for $T(b1,b2)$. But looking at the result, I can't go with $b(b2)-(ad-cd)(b1)$. Why?

2) What is limitation/restriction for linear transformation here? For example, can we use zero and one to make the calculation a lot easier? ( I know it won't work but want to know why it doesn't work).

Thanks!

Comment: In the general approach, you get the formula by row reducing the augmented matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & b & 1 & 0 \\ c & d & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ into the form $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & e & f \\ 0 & 1 & g & h \end{bmatrix}$. Then $\begin{bmatrix} e & f \\ g & h \end{bmatrix}$ is your inverse. One way to help check your formula is to look at examples where the inverse is obvious, like the identity matrix. For the identity matrix you have to have $ad-bc$ instead of $bc-ad$ because with $bc-ad$ you would get an inverse of $-I$, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: For illustration, the first step of this reduction gives $\begin{bmatrix} a & b & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & d-bc/a & -c/a & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Now you multiply the second row by $a$ and suddenly the formula starts to come together.

Comment: "To get rid of the second column, it seems like the order of subtraction matter. How can you tell which one should be subtracted by the other?" What do you mean by this?

Comment: Qudit, Sorry for the poor explanation. I meant that to get (0,1) vector for column2, I used linear transformation (same as I did for column1). And the first element needs to be zero. In order to get zero, I have two ways. b(b2)-(ad-cd)(b1) or (ad-cd)(b1)-b(b2) for T(b1,b2). But looking at the result, I can't go with b(b2)-(ad-cd)(b1)? Why?

Comment: lan, thank you for your answer but it didn't solve my question. Could you look at additional explanation above and give me a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the inverse of $A$ in general you row reduce the augmented matrix $\begin{bmatrix} A & I \end{bmatrix}$ into the form $\begin{bmatrix} I & B \end{bmatrix}$, then $B$ is the resulting inverse. So in the general $2 \times 2$ case you start with

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b & 1 & 0 \\ c & d & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Now you want to use row operations to cancel the $c$. Multiply the first row by $c/a$ to get

$$\begin{bmatrix} c & bc/a & c/a & 0 \\ c & d & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Now subtract the second row from the first row:

$$\begin{bmatrix} c & cb/a & c/a & 0 \\ 0 & d-bc/a & -c/a & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

For convenience let's clear the fractions:

$$\begin{bmatrix} ac & bc & c & 0 \\ 0 & ad-bc & -c & a \end{bmatrix}.$$

Now we need to cancel the $bc$, so we multiply the second row by $\frac{bc}{ad-bc}$, getting

$$\begin{bmatrix} ac & bc & c & 0 \\ 0 & bc & -\frac{bc^2}{ad-bc} & \frac{abc}{ad-bc} \end{bmatrix}.$$

Now we subtract the second row from the first row:

$$\begin{bmatrix} ac & 0 & c+\frac{bc^2}{ad-bc} & -\frac{abc}{ad-bc} \\ 0 & bc & -\frac{bc^2}{ad-bc} & \frac{abc}{ad-bc} \end{bmatrix}.$$

Now when you divide out the $ac$ and $bc$ in the first and second rows you get the result (some simplification is required in one place).

Note that in this argument I am assuming that $a,b,c$ and of course $ad-bc$ are all nonzero (since I divide by each of them at some point). Some small modifications are required when any of them are zero (in particular, row exchanges may be required).